# Facing difficulty while importing dependency in Angular2

Tags: angularjs, angular

Basically I have created a sample application by referring to Angular2 quickstart tutorial. For further digging I've created `./services/dataService.ts` service file like below.

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
@Injectable()
export class DataService {
    items: Array<number>;
    constructor() {
        this.items = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    }
    getItems() {
        return this.items;
    }
}
```

I had `"outDir": "../wwwroot/app",` option mentioned in `tsconfig` which transpile `app.ts` & `dataService.ts` to below path.

```
--wwwroot
 |app
   |--app.js
   |--services
      |-- dataService.js
```

**MyAppComponent**

```
import {Component, View, Inject, forwardRef} from 'angular2/core';
import {NgFor} from 'angular2/common';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {DataService} from './services/dataService';

@Component({
    'selector': 'my-app',
    template: `
            <div *ngFor="#item of items">
                {{item}}
            </div>
        `,
    directives: [NgFor],
    providers: [DataService]
})
export class MyAppComponent {
    items: Array<number>;
    constructor(service: DataService) {
        this.items = service.getItems();
    }
}
bootstrap(MyAppComponent)
```

> Code gets compiled with no-error, but after application Ran I got
>   below error, http://localhost:8413/app/services/dataService.

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

I used below code from `index.html` to load app files on page.

```
System.config({ packages: { src: { defaultExtension: 'js' } } });
System.import('app/app.js').then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

My question is how could I import the `dataService.js`, why does is give 404 error still its there in a place? I Researched alot on this problem, but didn't find anything helpful. Any help would appreciated.

**Edit**

Added `.tsconfig` to directly get rectify when there is issue

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "outDir": "../wwwroot/app",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Is `/app/services/dataservice` where the file is located?

Comment: @MarkPieszak no luck :(, now it don't allow me to build the application..

Comment: Does not appear to be an angular problem.  Suggest you post your gulpfile,js in another post tagged as such.

Comment: @TimMcNamara I know its not angular problem..& not related to gulp.js.. now I used `.tsconfig`'s `outDir` option to transpile file to correct path.. please take a look at update question..

Comment: In your package config change `src` to `app`. With that change you can remove the `.js` in your `System.import('app/app.js')`

Comment: @EricMartinez sorry to ask.. I don't get you.. what do you mean by `package config`? I don't have such file

Comment: @PankajParkar sorry I meant in your System config, change `{ packages: { src:` to `{ packages: { app:`

Comment: @EricMartinez tried the same..still getting same error. :( ` Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:8413/app/services/dataService` & the thing is I try same path with `.js` extension in browser, it seems working

Comment: @PankajParkar with the change I suggested above change this as well `import {DataService} from 'app/services/dataService';` (added `app` in the path) (sorry for going step by step)

Comment: @EricMartinez np sir.. I tried that after having `'app/services/dataService'` I'm getting compile time error..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102043/discussion-between-eric-martinez-and-pankaj-parkar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with configuration of `System`, previously I was having below code to load component.

```
System.config({ packages: { src: { defaultExtension: 'js' } } });
System.import('app/app.js').then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

Basically `System.config` settings tells that `packages` would be belongs to `src` folder and the files `defaultExtension` is `js`. So I changed my `packages`'s `src` to `app` as I was having `app` folder, not `src`.

Other than that I changed `System.import('app/app.js')` to `System.import('app/app')` as default extensions of files is `js`, so I don't need to bother about it. So my component loading script changed to below.

```
System.config({ packages: { app: { defaultExtension: 'js' } } });
System.import('app/app').then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```